# How do I create a post title that is a link in Blogger interface?

Tags: blogger, user-interface

In the old Blogger interface, when you were creating a post there was a box where you could place a URL that would turn the title into a hyperlink.  That box is gone in the new Blogger interface.

I've tried searching the [Blogger forums](http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!forum/blogger) that Google provides but found other people asking the same question, but no answers.

So how can I make the post title a hyperlink in the new Blogger interface?

Comment: Posting and self answering because I just spent a while searching for an answer and found a solution, but not one that I like.

Comment: Are you talking about a custom URL for the post or a click-through link for the title that would've taken a visitor to another site?

Comment: A click-through on the title - there was an explicit box for it in old Blogger that's not there in new Blogger - e.g. what's done for the post title on http://codingfortheman.blogspot.com/2012/04/testing-title-links.html.

Comment: Accepting my answer for now - but if anyone finds a better way, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option is now back in the new post interface, I noticed that a couple of weeks back: [‘Title Links’ back on Blogger](http://exde601e.blogspot.com/2012/09/title-links-back-on-blogger.html)

Answer (score 1):

One way I found to do this is to manually form a hyperlink in the title box.  For example, If my title is `Example Title`, and I want that to link to Wikipedia, I type

```
<a href="http://www.wikipedia.com">Example Title</a>
```

in the title box.

Comment: I also placed this answer in the Blogger forum with a pointer to come here - http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!searchin/blogger/title$20link/blogger/zKAZLk8-BQ8/_jOCwkpPfs8J